# Jquery get Google translate JSON text

Tags: jquery

This url with right api-key `https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=XXXXXXX&target=ru&source=en&q=hello` contains:

```
{
 "data": {
  "translations": [
   {
    "translatedText": "привет"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

URL works 100%, I tested it in browser.
You can read about it here - http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html

I want to get it with JQuery and insert in specific div:

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=XXXXXXX&target=ru&source=en&q=hello' 
$.get(url, function(response) {
    $('div#translation').html(response.data.translations[0].translatedText);
});
```

It is not working. `data` is empty. I cannot figure out where the problem is. It should work.
I tried to insert text from this url in local file and use it in url, then it works!

What is wrong here?

Comment: Same-Origin-Policy perhaps? Did you take a look at the error console of your browser? Chrome has it built in, for Firefox you need a plugin afaik.

Comment: I use Firebug. It shows that something is not right, but I can not find any details. It just make url red in its console. It should not be any policy, it is paid service. It is easily loaded with browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is the the Same-Origin-Policy mentioned by ZeissS.  Have a look at http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/using_rest_translate.html and read the section entitled "Using the callback argument".  This should avoid the same-origin-policy problem.

More information on JSONP and why it's sometimes needed can be found here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: It is the new stuff for me. It seems to be an answer.